# How to make multiple Column in archive Page?

Tags: loop

I want to create multiple column on archive page but dont want duplicate posts

please have look examples

http://www.firstpost.com/category/business

http://demos.gabfirethemes.com/advanced/category/technology/

i have seen "loop in action" (wp codex) but i want to create more then 4 loops

please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to create multiple loops in your archive template file. Each loop could pull posts from a different category if you want, just set the [category parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

In the codex there's a whole [section on multiple loops](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops) too.